# Connect to Heroku Postgres with Python: could not connect to server

Tags: python, postgresql, heroku, psycopg2

Been trying to connect PostgreSQL to my Python Discord bot on Heroku, and I directly followed the instructions here: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql#connecting-in-python

But I always get this error:

```
2021-05-21T01:34:16.512774+00:00 app[worker.1]:     cxn = psycopg2.connect(database=DATABASE_URL, sslmode='require')
2021-05-21T01:34:16.512776+00:00 app[worker.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 127, in connect
2021-05-21T01:34:16.512852+00:00 app[worker.1]:     conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
2021-05-21T01:34:16.512872+00:00 app[worker.1]: psycopg2.OperationalError: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
2021-05-21T01:34:16.512872+00:00 app[worker.1]:     Is the server running locally and accepting
2021-05-21T01:34:16.512873+00:00 app[worker.1]:     connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

Connection code:

```
from os import environ
from datetime import datetime
from apscheduler.triggers.cron import CronTrigger

DATABASE_URL = environ['DATABASE_URL']

cxn = None
cur = None


def connect():
    global cxn
    global cur
    cxn = psycopg2.connect(database=DATABASE_URL, sslmode='require')
    cur = cxn.cursor()

    # create the db for the first time
    cur.execute('''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS birthdays (
                        UserID integer PRIMARY KEY,
                        GuildID integer,
                        date text
                    );

                    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS channels (
                        GuildID integer PRIMARY KEY,
                        channel integer
                    );

                    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS messages (
                        MessageID integer PRIMARY KEY,
                        guild text,
                        channel text,
                        author text,
                        time text,
                        message text,
                        status text
                    );''')
    cxn.commit()

    time = datetime.now().strftime("[%H:%M:%S]")
    print(time, "Connected to Database")
```

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jV4pp.png) is the heroku addon page for the db

Comment: If anyone happens to have this problem in the future I eventually just solved using sqlalchemy rather than just psycopg2, source code here if you want to see it: https://github.com/Asi4nn/Shiver-Bot